# If else if cond in mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, how to add condition in aggregate $project

```js
Schedul.aggregate([
    { $match: { flag: 1 } },
    {
        $project: {
            "name": "$name",
            "day_of_week": ("$day_of_week" === 0) ? 'Sunday' : ("$day_of_week" === 1) ? 'Monday' : ("$day_of_week" === 2) ? 'Tuesday' : ("$day_of_week" === 3) ? 'Wednesday' : ("$day_of_week" === 4) ? 'Thursday' : ("$day_of_week" === 5) ? 'Friday' : 'Saturday',
        }
    },
])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`$switch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) aggregation instead.

```
Schedul.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "flag": 1 }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": "$name",
    "day_of_week": {
      "$switch": {
        "branches": [
          { "case": { "$eq": ["$day_of_week", 0] }, "then": "Sunday" },
          { "case": { "$eq": ["$day_of_week", 1] }, "then": "Monday" },
          { "case": { "$eq": ["$day_of_week", 2] }, "then": "Tuesday" },
          { "case": { "$eq": ["$day_of_week", 3] }, "then": "Wednesday" },
          { "case": { "$eq": ["$day_of_week", 4] }, "then": "Thrusday" },
          { "case": { "$eq": ["$day_of_week", 5] }, "then": "Friday" }
        ],
        "default": "Saturday"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```